# What's the right way to replace stp by str?

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, arm64

For some reasons, I need to replace `stp` instruction with `str`:

old:

```
stp q0, q0, [dst, -32]
```

new:

```
str q0, [dst, -32]
str q0, [dst, -24]
```

or

```
str q0, [dst, -24]
str q0, [dst, -32]
```

I have tried both orders, but both will end with segmentfault somewhere. Where goes wrong?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the reason why you need to replace `stp` with two `str`s?

Comment: @NateEldredge some platforms have cpu bug, stp seems to crash cpu in some radeon/mesa cases

Comment: Does `stp q,q` require 32-byte alignment on some CPUs?  Or is it not easily repeatable, more like a combination of microarchitectural conditions.  (Intel has had errata like that, like partial-register merging with hyper-threading enabled, leading to disabling the loop buffer on Skylake via a microcode update to work around it.  But it took a year or more before ocaml compiler devs noticed it, apparently their compiler generated code that sometimes triggered wrong behaviour.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I cannot get cpu vendor's support now so not sure does it require 32-byte alignment ;(. Yes, it is not easily repetable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`q0` is a 128-bit register, i.e. 16 bytes, so you want

```
str q0, [dst, -32]
str q0, [dst, -16]
```

or vice versa if you prefer (it should make no effective difference).

As it stands you are overlapping them and leaving the last 8 bytes uninitialized.